# Given a, b How many solutions exists for x, such that: $a \bmod{x}=b $

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, modules

Given $a, b$. How many solutions exists for $x$, such that: $$a \bmod{x}=b $$

By example:

$a = 21$ and $b = 5$

$21 \bmod{8} = 21 \bmod{16} = 5$

Then $x$ has 2 solutions

Comment: $b=a-nx$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$.  Rearrange to $nx=a-b$.

Comment: Do you mean $a \bmod x = b$, where $\bmod$ is the remainder operator which gives $0\le b < x$?

Comment: 0 < (a, b) < 1000000

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, consider that $a \equiv b \pmod x$ if and only if $a-b = kx$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.  Then $x=\frac{a-b}{k}$, hence there is precisely one $x$ for each divisor $k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.

Comment: How do you apply that with a= 9435152 and b = 272?. The answer is 282, but how it is?

Comment: I don't believe the answer is 282.  I get 360 solutions for $x$.

Comment: Are you sure?, please share your full solution

Comment: [wolfram solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=how+many+divisors&a=*C.divisors-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=9434880&f=FactorNumberCalculator.factinteger_9434880)

note that my previous solution I should have said there exists one $x$ for each _positive_ divisor $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function).

Comment: @JeffW89 I asked OP above for his/her intended question, and his/her answer of 282 seems to confirm my guess. You have to ignore those divisors less than or equal to $b$.

Comment: Ah ok I misunderstood the question!  To the OP, a solution without relying on a calculator is to consider the prime factorization $9,435,152-272=9,484,880=2^8\cdot 3^4\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 13$.  Notice that $(8+1)(4+1)(1+1)(1+1)(1+1)=360$.  Can you see what this product corresponds to?  And how to eliminate those divisors  $\leq 272$?